# Mongodb aggregation does't work with $match between times

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my code

```
Bill.aggregate(
    {$unwind:'$detais'},
    { $match : {
        createdOn : {
                $gt : moment().startOf('day'),
                $lt : moment().endOf('day')
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : '$detais.product_id',
            total : { $sum : '$detais.quantity' },
        }
    },
    { $sort :{ total: -1 } }
)
.limit(10)
.exec((err, records) => {
    if (err) {console.log(err)};
    res.send({
        data : records
    });
});
```

The query

```
createdOn : {
        $gt : moment().startOf('day'),
        $lt : moment().endOf('day')
}
```

work fine in another case.

But in aggregate is empty result... Please someone tell me where i'm mistake....

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `$and` condition in `$match`.

```
    Bill.aggregate({
            $unwind: '$detais'
        }, {
            $match: {
                createdOn: {
                    $and: [{
                            $gt: moment().startOf('day')
                        },
                        {
                            $lt: moment().endOf('day')
                        }]
                }
            });
```

Comment: Really thanks for reply me. I just found a solution. In my Bill Schema I set default `createdOn` by `Date.now`. But in my  $match . I use `moment().startOf('day')`.  There is a tiny diffrent here `Date.now()` return `2018-03-04T00:00:00.000Z`but `moment().startOf('day')` return `2018-03-04T00:00:00.000`.. what a crazy...

Comment: Ohh... okay no problem